# About 30 Days of Google Cloud

Tags: google-chrome, email, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-developers-console

I register for 30 Days of Google Cloud but I didn't receive mail yet.  when I get mail from 30 days of Google Cloud registered form.

Comment: Please be more clear, and your question may not be suitable here on SO. Are you referring to a training for a Google Cloud Badge?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to [contact Cloud Billing Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.150054582.1667126709.1632435085-62789406.1626116675)

See also:

- https://cloud.google.com/support/billing